# Process fields in SQLAlchemy model (using flask_sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, bleach

I am using SQLAlchemy through flask_sqlalchemy. A model receives input from HTML forms. I would like this input to be stripped of any tags. Instead of doing this several times in the code before assignment, I thought it might be better to implement this somehow in the model object.

The possibilities I could think of were:

- Derive own column types
- Wrap a proxy class around the column types
- Define kind of a decorator that does the above
- Modify the model object to intercept assignments

The first three solutions seem more elegant, but I don't understand how I need to implement these. The main reason is that I don't understand how exactly SQLAlchemy extracts the table structure and column types from the column variables, and how assignment to these is handled, in particular when access [through the flask_sqlalchemy class](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/).

I played around with the last option in the list above, and came up with this (partial) solution:

```
import bleach

class Example(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'examples'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    field1 = db.Column(db.Text)
    field2 = db.Column(db.String(64))

    _bleach_columns = ('field1', 'field2')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs is not None:
            for key in Example._bleach_columns:
                kwargs[key] = bleach.clean(kwargs[key], tags=[], strip=True)
        super(Example, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

This works when creating objects using `Example(field1='foo', field2='bar')`. However, I am uncertain how to handle the assignment of individual fields. I was thinking of something along these lines, but am unsure about the parts marked as ASSIGN:

```
    def __setattr__(self, attr, obj):
        if(attr in Example._bleach_columns):
            ASSIGN(..... , bleach.clean(obj, tags=[], strip=True))
        else:  
            ASSIGN(..... , obj)
```

More generally, my impression is that this is not the best way to handle tag filtering. I'd therefore appreciate any hint on how to best implement this behaviour, ideally with a decorator of new column types.

It looks like this could be done with a TypeDecorator ([link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html)) that applies bleach in `process_bind_param`. However, I could not figure out how to apply this decorator to the flask_sqlalchemy based column definition in the db.Model-derived class above.

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to solve this... which was easy, as usual, once one understands what it all is about.

The first thing was to understand that `db.Column` is the same than SQLAlchemy's `column`. I thus could use the same syntax. To implement variable length strings, I used a class factory to return the decorators. If there is another solution to implement the length, I'd be interested to hear about it. Anyway, here is the code:

```
def bleachedStringFactory(len):

    class customBleachedString(types.TypeDecorator):

        impl = types.String(len)

        def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
            return bleach.clean(value, tags=[], strip=True)

        def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
            return value

    return customBleachedString


class Example(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'examples'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    field1 = db.Column(bleachedStringFactory(64), unique=True)
    field2 = db.Column(bleachedStringFactory(128))
```